# casting func type to other func type

Tags: go, casting

I have some workers. I don't want to spread source type through my packages but to user interfaces. Hence I have:

```
package package_one

type T func(map[string]interface{}) interface{}

func Func(f T) {
    package_two.Func(f)
}

package package_two

...

type T func(map[string]interface{}) interface{}

func Func(f T) {
    fmt.Printf("%v", f(nil))
}

...

package main

func main() {
    package_one.Func(func(m map[string]interface{}) interface{} {
        return "result"
    })
}
```

I get the error when `package_one.Func()` calls `package_two.Func()` . I assume that despite equal signature compiler doesn't treat `package_one.T` and `package_two.T` as the same type. Why does it happen? I want to avoid runtime casting and checking the result as it's verbose and demands error handling. Life might be easier if I can define it as the same types on compile stage. Is it possible?

Comment: 1. There is no type casting _at all_ in Go. 2. Yes, `package_one.T` is distinct from `package_two.T`. 3. What you probably want is to define an interface, and all of the types it depends on, in a central location, then let your `package_one` and `package_two` implement that interface.

Comment: The conversion `package_two.Func(package_two.T(f))` doesn't require runtime checking of any "result" and neither does it demand any error handling. If the conversion is illegal it will be caught at compile time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Convert](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) the value using the expression `package_two.T(f)`.  There is no runtime cost to this conversion. There are no errors to check with a conversion.

```
package package_one

import "play.ground/package_two"

type T func(map[string]interface{}) interface{}

func Func(f T) {
    package_two.Func(package_two.T(f))
}
```

Run it on the playground.  https://play.golang.org/p/3umm81iNAjk